# How to read all parameters in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, checkpoint

I want to make a txt file which contains weights and biases of each layers. 
So I tried to extract those parameters from checkpoint file as below

```
....
log = open("/home/extract_weights/weight.txt","w")
print(tf.contrib.framework.load_variable('/home/extract_weights/weight',"Variable_4/Adam"),file=log)
log.close()
```

After that, when I open the weight.txt file, It doesn't show all parameters of 'Variable_4/Adam'. Because the'Variable_4/Adam' has so many parameters, it shows some of the parameters as '...,' as below.

```
[[[ -3.28861130e-03  -4.36393253e-04   2.71450588e-03 ...,
     -1.02883030e-03   7.19045638e-04   2.01382302e-03]
   [ -2.78162770e-04  -9.16915829e-04   6.41513802e-03 ...,
     -1.56752067e-05   1.02308008e-03   4.38673422e-03]
   [ -2.39563966e-03  -1.86417182e-03   6.60661049e-03 ...,
     -1.80270139e-03  -1.77437195e-03   6.22929214e-03]
   ...,
   [ -5.03436942e-03  -7.72555824e-04   4.88848845e-03 ...,
     -1.42029661e-03  -2.02224823e-03   6.00241497e-03]
   [ -3.24321515e-03   7.12389883e-05   3.92327132e-03 ...,
     -5.55949169e-04   6.48389920e-04   4.28168190e-04]
   [ -2.34445534e-03  -1.03506667e-03   5.81974722e-03 ...,
     -1.64756668e-03  -8.65898794e-04   6.68829679e-03]]

  [[ -5.87272050e-04  -6.52794901e-04   5.46910102e-03 ...,
     -2.80088483e-04  -1.18806446e-03   2.98094237e-03]
   [  1.95095991e-03  -1.39068766e-03   7.42691476e-03 ...,
    -5.30915044e-04  -6.42847299e-05   1.92967139e-03]
   [ -6.43472234e-03  -3.83679318e-04   3.45606497e-03 ...,
    -5.63960406e-04  -1.46852643e-03   5.95639553e-03]
   ...,
```

How can I save all parameters of each layers in txt file??

Comment: I find eval().tofile :)